# How to solve Straight line questions

Tags: math

If a line l is passing through the points (k,2k),(3k,3k) and (3,1) and the distance through the origin is

a)1/root 5     b)3/root 5      c)2/root 5     d)4/root 5
Please how to find this type of questions? 
Please explain in brief?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Yes ,i don't know how to post a question in mathematics?Please let me know the details?

Comment: Here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just the slope of the two segments the same, setup the equation, and solve for k.

Comment: after getting the values and the equation,am not getting the value from the above four options.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Write line equation in a [general form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#General_.28or_standard.29_form)

```
A * x + B * y + C = 0
```

Substitute given point coordinates in this equation, solve equation system (3 eq's), find coefficients A, B, C.

Use them to find [distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) to coordinate origin.

It seems not very hard to read a pair of wiki pages, isn't it?